# Existence of pullback of fiber bundles from abstract nonsense?

Tags: category-theory, fiber-bundles, limits-colimits, grothendieck-topologies

Let $\mathsf C$ be a superextensive site with products.

A trivial fiber bundle is a bundle $\pi:E\rightarrow B$ which is isomorphic to $\pi_1:B\times F\rightarrow B$ in $\mathsf{C}/B$.

Let $\mathcal M$ be a class of arrows in $\mathsf C$. An arrow $\pi:E\rightarrow B$ is said to be *locally in* $\mathcal M$ if there's a covering $ \left\{u_i: U_i\rightarrow B \right\}$ such that $u_i^\ast(\pi)$ are all in $\mathcal M$.

A fiber bundle with fiber $F$ is an arrow which is locally a product projection of the form $X\times F\longrightarrow X$.

I'm trying to figure out whether the fact pullbacks exist for fiber bundles follows from these definitions in this generality. Let $\mathcal M$ be the class of product projections. My questions are:

1. Is $\mathcal M$ stable under base change? (I think so because limits commute with limits, but I'm not sure whether this is actually right here.)
2. Is the class of arrows locally in $\mathcal M$ stable under base change? (Again I'm tempted to just wave my hands and say everything here is just limits and they commute, so sure, but I'm not sure.)
3. Is the class of arrows locally in $\mathcal M$ stable under base change assuming only $\mathcal M$ is? (Again, I'm guessing yes.)

Comment: If you have all binary products then product projections are closed under pullback. Existence of anything else must be assumed.

Comment: @ZhenLin by everything else do you mean all relevant pullbacks?

Comment: Yes – the point being that you don't have any assumptions that allow you to glue things together.

Comment: @ZhenLin okay, so just making sure - if all products and pullbacks exist (if the category is complete), then 1,2,3 are all correct, and this is by commutation of limits and limits?

Comment: It's not quite that trivial. You also need to use the axioms of a Grothendieck topology.

Comment: @ZhenLin from my proofs I found the fiber (second factor of the product) is invariant under pullback, i.e the pullback of a (nontrivial) fiber bundle has the same fiber. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's basically the pullback pasting lemma.